# Normality through the time

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'am faced with a strange problem and I can't find a way out. Here it is:

We observe data $X(t)$ that depends on the time $t$. We make these observations at given times $t_0, \cdots, t_n$ for a $n \in \mathbb{N}$. At each of these times, we check if the data are normal using a normality test (Anderson-Darling, Shapiro-Wilk, D'Agostino) to make a capability study, i.e. to compute a Ppk (process performance index).
The problem is that we observe normality for $X(t_0), \cdots, X(t_{k-1})$, no normality for $X(t_k)$ and again normality for $X(t_{k+1}),\cdots, X(t_n)$ for $0 < k < n$.
Let us call $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ the mean respectively the standard deviation of $X(t_i)$ for $i \in \{0,\cdots,n\}$.
I observed $\mu_{k+1} < \mu_k < \mu_{k-1}$ and $\sigma_{k+1} < \sigma_k < \sigma_{k-1}$, letting me assume that the Ppk at time $t_k$ has to be somewhere between the one at $t_{k-1}$ and at $t_{k+1}$.

I was also thinking of showing that $(X(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a stochastic Gaussian process, but I suppose if I don't have normality at every step I cannot assume it.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

P.S:
The definition I used for the Ppk is the following:
$$
Ppk = \min\left( \frac{\mu-LSL}{3\sigma},\frac{USL - \mu}{3\sigma}\right),
$$
where $USL$ and $LSL$ mean respectively upper specification limit and lower specification limit and are given.

Answer (score 1):

How confident are you that $X(t_k)$ really is that unusual?

If you test $100$ different *normal* distributions for normality, the $p$-values will be $100$ different uniformly sampled values from $[0,1]$. As a result, you expect that, on average, $5$ of them will randomly happen to be significant at the $0.05$ level, and $1$ of them will randomly happen to be significant at the $0.01$ level. This does not mean that one of them is not normal - it is a natural result of doing $100$ null hypothesis tests.

So if the *only* reason you have of being suspicious of $X(t_k)$ is that it has a fairly low $p$-value, then you should probably stop being suspicious of it. The likeliest explanation is that you have a normal distribution at every time step, and at time $t_k$ it just happened to produce not-very-normal-looking data.

If your response is, "But $X(t_k)$ had a **really really low** $p$-value!!" then we can try to do some meta-analysis of the $p$-values to see how unusual it is that you'd get one that low over $n$ time steps. This is an entire statistical field that can't be summarized in a single answer.

But one conservative test is: if you are testing things at, say, a $0.01$ significance level, but your only reason to suspect $X(t_k)$ is that it had the lowest $p$-value out of $n$ time steps, then you should be comparing that $p$-value to $\frac{0.01}{n}$ instead. The probability that the *most extreme* $p$-value after you've done $n$ tests is less than $\frac{0.01}{n}$ is equal to $$1 - \left(1 - \frac{0.01}{n}\right)^n$$
which for any value of $n$ is somewhere between $0.01$ and $0.00995$. So if your most extreme $p$-value is less than $0.01$ but bigger than $\frac{0.01}{n}$, that's not really a reason to suspect $X(t_k)$ of not being normal. If, on the other hand, you got a $p$-value of less than $\frac{0.01}{n}$, then that's suspiciously low even for the most extreme of your $p$-values.

Comment: Thank you Misha Lavrov,
It is a very complete and useful answer. I have to think about it. So the field that study the 'behavior' of p-values is called meta-analysis of p-value? 
Also the problem is that the same data are taken to do normality test and the characteristics of the data (from medication) change with the time but 'should' be normal. I think to apply your reasoning, I should do multiple measurement at one time point and then compute the p-value.

Comment: Yes; in general, meta-analysis is asking the question "we've done many statistical tests; how do we think about them all together?"

Comment: Because we are testing if $X(t)$ is normal at a given time $t$. It can be normal but the mean and the standard deviation will be for sure different of the mean and standard deviation of $X(t')$ if $t' \neq t$.

Comment: Misha Lavrov, can you say me from where did you get that we have to compare the p-value to 0.01/n and how you calculate the probability $1- \left( 1-\frac{0.01}{n}\right)^n$ please?

Comment: For $x$ close to $0$, $(1-x)^n$ is approximately $1-nx$, and so if we want to choose $q$ so that $1 - (1-q)^n$ is approximately $0.01$, then we want to take $q = 0.01/n$.

Comment: Thank you one more time for the answer. But i don't see from where it comes. As much as I understood, you said that the p-value is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then, for each test, the probability that the p-value is bigger or equal to the significance level $\alpha$ supposing that our data passed the test(i.e. they are normally distributed) is $1-\alpha$, right? Then, the probability that after $n$ tests the p-value is bigger than $\alpha$ is $(1-\alpha)^n$ with the same supposition as before and taking into account that each p-values are independent.

Comment: Then, the probability of having a p-value less than $\alpha$ after the n-test should be $\alpha(1-\alpha)^n$, no? I don't understand how you have found $1- (1-\alpha/n)^n$.

Comment: The probability that every $p$-value is bigger than $\alpha$ is $(1-\alpha)^n$. The probability that some $p$-value is smaller than $\alpha$ is $1 - (1-\alpha)^n$. This is approximately equal to $1 - (1-\alpha n) = \alpha n$ for small $\alpha$. We want the result to be $0.01$, so we set $\alpha = \frac{0.01}{n}$.

Comment: Is it the Bonferroni method? if yes, isn't it to control the FWER that apply to multiple testing on the same dataset? So we cannot apply it here since the data set is different through the time right?

Comment: @FHg I have no clue what gave you that impression, but if you're reading sources that tell you about things like the Bonferroni method, then you can probably choose your favorite method on your own now :)

Comment: Thanks Misha Lavrov :). Do you know the name of your technique? Does it have a name? Or do you have any sources? I don't think I can apply Bonferroni.

Comment: I mean, yes, this is the Bonferroni correction. "Can't apply" is the wrong formulation, though; it just might be a unnecessarily conservative test compared to fancier ones.

Comment: I have still doubts on the possibility to use p-value correction based on the FWER since the experiment design is such that we have a family of hypotheses test each applied to different data. You know?